# How to sparsely read a large file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, file-io

I ran a simulation which wrote a huge file to disk. The file is a big matrix `v`. I can't read it all, but I really only need a portion of the matrix, say, 1:100 of the columns and rows. I'd like to do something like

```
vtag = dlmread('v',1:100:end, 1:100:end);
```

Of course, that doesn't work. I know I should have only done the following when writing to the file

```
dlmwrite('vtag',v(1:100:end, 1:100:end));
```

But I did not, and running everything again would take two more days.

Thanks

Amir

Comment: You don't have a choice but to parse the file manually and skip every 100 lines yourself.  Can you tell us what the matrix looks like?  How many rows and columns does this matrix have?

Comment: it is 6000*3000, each entry is 14 digits long.

Comment: Looks like Suever beat me to it. Check his answer.

Comment: @CuriousMe Just curious, if your data is only 6000x3000, how come you can read that into memory at once? That shouldn't be that big because as a `double` that's only 144MB

Comment: Eventually it reads it all, but it might take a very long time. Too long, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thankfully the [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) function supports specifying a range to read as [the third input](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html#inputarg_R1). So if you wan to read all `N` columns for the first 100 rows, you can specify that with the following command

```
startRow = 1;
startColumn = 1;
endRow = 100;
endColumn = N;

rng = [startRow, startColumn, endRow, endColumn] - 1;
vtag = dlmread(filename, ',', rng);
```

**EDIT Based on your clarification**

Since you don't want `1:100` rows but rather `1:100:end` rows, the following approach should work better for you.

You can use `textscan` to read chunks of data at a time. You can read a "good" row and then read in the next "chunk" of data to ignore (discarding it in the process), and continue until you reach the end of the file.

The code below is a slight modification of that idea, except it utilizes the [`HeaderLines`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#input_argument_namevalue_headerlines) input to `textscan` which instructs the function how many lines to ignore before reading in the data. The first time through the loop, no lines will be skipped, however all other times through the loop, `rows2skip` lines will be skipped. This allows us to "jump" through the file very rapidly without calling any additional file opertions.

```
startRow = 1;

rows2skip = 99;
columns = 3000;

fid = fopen(filename, 'rb');

% For now, we'll just assume you're reading in floating-point numbers
format = repmat('%f ', [1 columns]);

count = 1;

lines2discard = startRow - 1;

while ~feof(fid)
    % Use "HeaderLines" to skip data before reading in data we care about
    row = textscan(fid, format, 1, 'Delimiter', ',', 'HeaderLines', lines2discard);
    data{count} = [row{:}];

    % After the first time through, set the "HeaderLines" (i.e. lines to ignore) 
    % to be the # we want to skip between lines (much faster than alternatives!)
    lines2discard = rows2skip;

    count = count + 1;
end

fclose(fid);

data = cat(1, data{:});
```

You may need to adjust your [format specifier](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#inputarg_formatSpec) for your own type of input.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, but this isn't whay I want to do. I want to skip every 100 rows, not to read the first 100.

Comment: @CuriousMe answer has been updated with the approach that should work for what you need.